# 1D Terrain Generation in Java

Tags: maps, tiles, noise

Not able to implement Perlin Noise for 1D Random Terrain Generation. I've tried everywhere and I cannot find anything useful, sure I sort of understand Perlin Noise but everytime I try it nothing works. I'm using LibGDX in Java if that helps, thanks.

Here is the code for P.N.

```
static float Noise(int x) {
    x = (x << 13) ^ x;
    return (float) (1.0 - ((x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & Integer.MAX_VALUE) / 1073741824f);

}

public static float PerlinNoise1D(float x, float persistence, int octaves) {
    float total = 0;
    float p = persistence;
    int n = octaves - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

        float frequency = (float) Math.pow(2, i);
        double amplitude = Math.pow(p, i);
        total += InterpolatedNoise(x * frequency) * amplitude;
    }

    return (int) total;

}

private static float InterpolatedNoise(float x) {
    int integer_X = (int) x;
    float fractional_X = x - integer_X;

    float v1 = SmoothNoise1D(integer_X);
    float v2 = SmoothNoise1D(integer_X + 1);

    return CosineInterpolate(v1, v2, fractional_X);

}

public static float CosineInterpolate(float a, float b, float x) {
    float ft = (float) (x * Math.PI);
    float f = (float) ((1 - Math.cos(ft)) * 0.5);

    return a * (1 - f) + b * f;
}

public static float SmoothNoise1D(int x) {
    return Noise(x) / 2 + Noise(x - 1) / 4 + Noise(x + 1) / 4;
}
```

and here is the code for the for loop used to render the tiles (assuming my tiles are 32px x 32px)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); i++) {
    float y = PerlinNoise1D(i, 5f, 3);
    for (int j = (int) (y); j < Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); j++) {
        hudBatch.begin();
        hudBatch.draw(hp, i, j);
        hudBatch.end();
        j+=31;
    }
    i+=31;
}
```

P.S I'm sort of trying to create a terraria-like game.

Comment: Are you trying to use perlin/simplex noise as a heightmap?

Comment: Yes, just to generate random hills with a seed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but it's probably the i++ in the first line of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); i++) {
    float y = PerlinNoise1D(i, 5f, 3);
    //other stuff
}
```

Since gradient noise is smooth at small intervals and abrupt at big intervals try and scale the value. Something like:

```
float y = PerlinNoise1D(i * 0.1, 5f, 3);
```

Comment: I swear I've tried that, awesome it worked... Now I just need to replace little 1x1 pixels with tiles, any idea on how to go about that? Again I need the tiles to be destructible sort of like a sandbox game. Here's the result of the change, before the hills were more spiky. [here's a picture of it](http://i.imgur.com/u0tBmPT.png)

Comment: @hzyy You're drawing pixel-per-pixel?? I recommend to at least learn how to draw sprites/textures. Imagine a square with a picture on top. They could be your tiles & I'm quite sure it's faster than per pixel.